# Добавление класса Active в один из тегов div в реальном времени

Tags: javascript, html

Вопрос: Как составить скрипт, который в реальном времени рандомно добавляет класс **Active** в любой тег  c классом **item**.

```
<div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы хоть что-нибудь пробовали сделать для этого? и причем здесь ajax?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/urto5mv7/

Comment: Создать рандом я знаю, но как сделать так чтобы через каждый 3 сек класс **Active** перескакивал рандомно с одного <div class="item"> на другой, без перезагрузки страницы? Скрипт ajax выполняет функции в реальном времени, поэтому и добавил.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос из категории "Напишите за меня код"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
setInterval(function(){
var random = parseInt((Math.random()) * 3);
var remove = parseInt((Math.random()) * 3);
var res = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
res[random].classList.add('active');
if(random != remove)
res[remove].classList.remove('active');
},3000);
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.item {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, видимо я не грамотно составил вопрос. Мне необходимо чтобы код срабатывал каждый 3 сек без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: проверьте я добавил

Comment: да каждые 3 секунды

Comment: Через 3 сек добавляет **active** во все теги <div class="item">. Но необходимо чтобы класс **active** добавлялся рандомно в один из тегов <div class="item"> и через каждый 3 секунды рандомно перескакивал из одного <div class="item"> на другой <div class="item">.

Comment: Пример: [sk-ellada.com](http://sk-ellada.com/)

Comment: сделал проверьте